# Как добавить картинку в Circle?

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class Moon extends Circle {

    public Moon(double x, double y) {
        this.setCenterX(x);
        this.setCenterY(y);
        this.setRadius(25);
        this.setFill(Color.CYAN); 

    }
```

Спрашивал на английском форуме, там сказали, что дубликат вопроса:
[**Вот**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116313/how-to-set-an-image-in-a-circle)

Пытался вклеить внутрь следующий код:

```
File file = new File("moon.png");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
Image mn = new Image(path);
this.setFill(new ImagePattern(mn));
```

Но проблема в том, что при таком действии мне выкидывает окно 
"Hot code replace failed - Scheme change not implemented", затем отказывается компайлить, что делает дальнейшие попытки как-либо использовать этот код и, соответственно, *тот* ответ бесполезными для моего случая. Хотел бы знать ваше мнение, как с этим бороться. Возможно такое возникает из-за того, что там круг создавался через

```
Circle moon = new Circle();
```

Когда у меня

```
Public class Moon extends Circle{...}
```

Так же не уверен, правильно ли взял путь к картинке, ибо путь к ней:
 ***/eclipse-workspace/ProjectName/src/sample/moon.png

Comment: "Hot code replace failed - Scheme change not implemented" означает что нужно рестартовать приложение.

Comment: Все еще ожидаю ответа, ибо не компайлит